# git pull a specific tag only

Tags: git, git-pull

I looking for command to make my life easiest.

**The issue:**
have a project with sources.
along of time i pushed more versions: v1.0.1 until v1.0.14 (latest)
the version v1.0.12 is an patch and fixes special for myserver, 
but the myserver actually have installed v1.0.10 (I should update from v1.0.10 to v1.0.12)

**the question:**
how to make an command to update the specific server to the looking version v1.0.12

i know command git pull but not understand how to do correct way
also i want some options to prevent merge conflicts

the start point is command that i made:

```
$ git pull --rebase origin refs/tags/1.0.13:refs/tags/1.0.13
From http://192.168.0.12/gitlab/AF-NG/frontend-dist
* [new tag]         1.0.13     -> 1.0.13
* [new tag]         1.0.11     -> 1.0.11
* [new tag]         1.0.12     -> 1.0.12
* [new tag]         1.0.14     -> 1.0.14
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: 2.0.0
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
------
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging styles/css/production.min.css
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in file.css
When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort"
```

Comment: Do you want to **checkout** v1.0.12 on some server? Or do you want to integrate v1.0.12 with your local non-pushed/shared commits?

Comment: _I looking for command to make my life easiest._ Aren't we all?

Comment: `git pull` means `git fetch` and then run a second Git command, usually `git merge` although you can tell it to use `git rebase` instead. I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`. Just use `git fetch` followed by the command you want, which in this case seems to be `git checkout`.

Comment: **Lasse V. Karlsen:** I want to integrate v1.0.12 with your local non-pushed/shared commits

Comment: I never use **git fetch** until now (use only git pull from IDE), and I unknown correct flow to run commands, step by step. your support will be appreciable. tx

Comment: another example for pull (merge way): ```git pull origin master:1.0.13```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the solution that I find is:

1. `$ git fetch -unf origin 1.0.12:refs/tags/1.0.12`
2. `$ git checkout 1.0.12`

if remote changes wants to merge with current will make a:
`$ git merger 1.0.12`

please tell me if my way is right

Comment: Would be helpful if you included why you would use ```-unf``` for your fetch. I've read the man page for these flags but it would make this answer more complete as to why you are using these 3 flags. I understand why ```-no-tags```, I slightly understand ```--force``` for the refspec part (maybe), but not sure on the ```--update-head-ok``` option.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `git checkout` to checkout the tag you want. This will make the working directory the same as it was when you created the tag.